# reCAPTCHA not working in popup contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, recaptcha

recaptcha working fine in my contact page. but there are other two forms which comes in popup window. in that recaptcha is not showing.`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***********************"></div>`

Comment: Can you please provide more details of it?

Comment: I have integrated the sitekey and secret key. its working fine in my contact page. but it is not showing in the form which opens in a popup window.

Comment: Can you please provide site link so i can check it.

Comment: did you check JS error anything occur while pop-up open

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem, but double-check to make sure that the page in question is loading the Google reCAPTCHA JS (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js at the time of writing).

In my case (using Magnific Popup, btw), the Google reCAPTCHA JS script wasn't being loaded on pages that demonstrated the problem. This code in the [Contact From 7 reCAPTCHA plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-recaptcha/) was malfunctioning and was the source of the problem:

```
function wp_footer()
{
    if( count( $this->ids ) )
    {
        wp_print_scripts('contact_form_7_recaptcha_script');
    }
}
```

I commented out the `if()` statement:

```
function wp_footer()
{
    // Commented out to ensure that the JS is always loaded, regardless of the value of `$this->ids`.
    // if( count( $this->ids ) )
    // {
        wp_print_scripts('contact_form_7_recaptcha_script');
    // }
}
```

Now, the reCAPTCHA JS is always loaded and the reCAPTCHA element appears in my contact form within the popup.